# Problem with *.svg logo showing on my website

Tags: html, css, web, graphical-logo

Good day to everyone!
I'm new here & in web design.
Have some problem with my study project.
In my study material (website), logo showing well, but once I change image in original *.svg file it disappears. Try searching the web, but all solutions was not help me.
[This is how logo looks in study materials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcWiY.png)

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
    <script src="libs/rain.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="logo" style="background-image: url(/img/logo.svg);"></div>

    <section class="layers">
        <div class="layers__container">
            <div class="layers__item layer-1" style="background-image: url(/img/layer-1.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="layers__item layer-2">
                <div class="hero-content">
                    <h1>Red Maple Leaf<span>Studios</span></h1>
                    <div class="hero-content__p">Creating a beautiful 3D website with a ‘lens effect’</div>
                    <button class="button-start">Exlore music</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="layers__item layer-4">
                <canvas class="rain"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="layers__item layer-5" style="background-image: url(img/layer-5.png);"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root {
    --index: calc(1vw + 1vh);
    --transition: 1.5s cubic-bezier(.05, .5, 0, 1);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: kamerik-3d;
    src: url(../fonts/kamerik205-heavy.woff2);
    font-weight: 900;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: merriweather-italic-3d;
    src: url(../fonts/merriweather-regular-italic.woff2);
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #7c222a;
    font-family: kamerik-3d;
}
.logo {
    --logo-size: calc(var(--index) * 7.8);
    width: var(--logo-size);
    height: var(--logo-size);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(51% - calc(var(--logo-size) / 2));
    top: calc(var(--index) * 2.8);
    z-index: 1;
}
.layers {
    perspective: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.layers__container {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(var(--move-y)) rotateY(var(--move-x));
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform var(--transition);
}
.layers__item {
    position: absolute;
    inset: -5vw;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.layer-1 {
    transform: translateZ(-55px) scale(1.06);
}
.layer-5 {
    transform: translateZ(300px) scale(.9);
}

.hero-content {
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * 2.9);
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: calc(var(--index) * -.15);
    line-height: 1.35em;
    margin-top: calc(var(--index) * 5.5);
}
.hero-content span {
    display: block;
}
.hero-content__p {
    text-transform: none;
    font-family: merriweather-italic-3d;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * .73);
    line-height: 3;
}
.button-start {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: calc(var(--index) * .71);
    letter-spacing: -.02vw;
    padding: calc(var(--index) * .7) calc(var(--index) * 1.25);
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #7c222a;
    border-radius: 10em;
    border:#7c222a (255 255 255 / .4) 3px solid;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: calc(var(--index) * 2.5);
}
.layer-4, .layer-5 {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If problem in svg format, could you please advise helpful solution for me.
Maybe I can change something in this code.
Thank you!

I try to search web, but all solutions that I find there, was not help me.
I'm looking for the help & for solution. I want understand one thing, problem in this *.svg file or in my code.

Comment: Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the actual svg you're referring to. We don't need all the header fluff, buttons and other irrelevant code / CSS.

Comment: Include the source code (copy and paste the contents of the file) for `logo.svg` in your question. You say that the code works but the svg doesnt. So show the svg code here so that it can be inspected.

Comment: How I can add this *.svg file here? Only via external link?

Comment: Hmmm .... Did you create the svg file or did you get it from somewhere? I'm suspecting the latter. ... Its possible that the svg file isn't being found by the browser. Open your browser dev tools (try the F12 key) and see if you see any errors related to the svg not found.

Comment: I got it from study package. Once I open it in Adobe Illustrator & change image in it, it stops working properly. If I don't change anything in study package, it looks well, like on screenshot, if I made any changes, it disappears.

Comment: svg files should be XML so you should be able to post it in a code section, eg <svg width="24" height="24"><path d="M6 4v17l6-4 6 4V4c0-.6-.4-1-1-1H7a1 1 0 00-1 1z" fill-rule="nonzero"></path></svg>

Comment: I can place this anywhere in my code or in which section?

Comment: @nas2toll as another code block below the css?

Comment: Does your logo include a raster image? (tree background image). If so make sure the image gets embedded when saving the svg again. If you open the svg in an text editor you see a data chunk like `<image href="data:image/jpeg;base64, ...` So check your export/svg saving options in AI